# If columnar is the adverb for column, what is the adverb for row?

Tags: terminology, latin

Some linear algebra algorithms used for computing statistics or storing datasets deal with matrices on a column-by-column basis. As such, they can be referred to as being **columnar**. What would be the equivalent adverb for algorithms that work on a row-by-row basis? A similar question on [Answers.com](http://www.answers.com/Q/Is_there_an_adverb_for_row) seems to indicate that no such adverb exists, and all I can think of is really not satisfying (to say the least):

- **Rowar** (neologism) looks and sounds ugly
- **Rownar** isn't much better
- **Linear** could be misconstrued
- **Linar** (pronounced `lahy-ner`) might be the least worst of them

Any better idea?

Comment: Given that matrices are used throughout mathematics (they're not restricted to statistics!), and that this is a question of English usage of adverbs to refer to a mathematical object, you may get more traction on either math.SE or english.SE. I'd suggest flagging the question and asking the mods to move it.

Comment: Sounds good. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: I think belongs better on the non-learner site, or on Math.SE. Or at least my answer does

Comment: I 100% agree with @ssdecontrol - I am mystified why this was taken to ELL rather than english.stackexchange or math.stackexchange - either of which would be a better fit.

Comment: I agree with @ssdecontrol. We might even consider moving it back to stats.SE.

Comment: It seems you really are looking for an adjective. Columnar is an adjective.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

*WARNING: this is my opinion, but I consider myself educated on the topic. I was a straight-A Latin student for most of a decade, and geeking out over language and etymology is one of my hobbies.*

The correct counterpart is **tabular**.

> tabulatum, tabulati  N  N     2 2  N   [XXXCX]
>   floor, story; layer, row; tier formed by the horizontal branches of a tree;

*source: http://www.archives.nd.edu/cgi-bin/wordz.pl?english=row*

But the word you actually want, an adverb that means "operates on columns," is in fact **column-wise**, and its row-oriented counterpart is **row-wise**. The words "columnar" and "tabular," at least the way I see them used, more properly refer to data than to an algorithm.

This is because the suffix **-ar** (as in *familiar*) is derived from the Latin **-aris**, in turn derived from **-alis** (see, e.g. the "origin" section [here](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/-al?s=t)) which is where we get the suffix **-al** (as in *familial*). Both suffixes mean the same thing as their Latin roots: "of or related to." Consider the difference in connotation between *familiar*, *familial*, and *family-wise*. Note also that, of these three, *family-wise* is the only one that makes sense as an adverb rather than an adjective.

**Data**

- **tabular**: arranged in rows
- **columnar**: arranged in columns

#### Algorithms:

- **row-wise**: operates on rows
- **column-wise**: operates on columns.

Also, my thanks to Glen_b for reminding me about the term "row-wise."

Comment: Where did you get the information that "-aris" derived from "-alis"? Can you provide a reference? Can't they be just parallel suffixes that existed in the language and happened to have the same meaning?

Comment: @Giorgio edited. I was always under the impression that they were in fact parallel suffixes, until I went to write this answer

Comment: Since the question specifically asked about *adverbs*, not *adjectives*, and "tabular" and "columnar" are adjectival (as you point out), the correct adverb could not be tabular, and the one being sought would be row-wise. Further, while you describe well the origin of *tabular*, if we're to avoid the genetic fallacy, we'd have to consider how the word *tabular* is presently understood in statistical applications (where it means "organized as a table" -- i.e. into *rows* and *columns*).[1][2][3]   ... (ctd)

Comment: @Glen_b good point about the adverb. I made an edit to reflect that

Comment: (ctd)... As such tabular doesn't work - neither its present meaning nor its status as an adjective would let it qualify. Refs: 1. definition 1 [here](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/tabular); 2. definition 2 [here](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tabular); 3. definition 3 [here](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/tabular). None of those references include a meaning like row-wise. Good knowledge of Latin (and no doubt yours is better than mine) doesn't always help us when seeking present meanings. While I disagree with the conclusion I think this answer is very interesting.

Comment: @Glen_b typically I think "columnar" implies both columns and rows as well. So the issue is reciprocal. Of course tabular really means "arranged in a table" but what is a table without rows?

Comment: Perhaps it usually does (I can't say I've seen it more than a couple of times) - but the original post is specifically asking about using it as "an adverb for column".

Answer (score 8):

I'd suggest "*row-wise*" or "*by rows*". As in "R stores a matrix in columnar fashion, while some other languages store them row-wise"  (though I usually wouldn't usually use 'columnar' myself; I'd more likely say "R stores a matrix column-by-column" or something equally descriptive).

Comment: In that case, would you also use "column-wise" for consistency purposes, or would you stick to "columnar"?

Comment: It depends on the context. If I was responding to someone else's use of *columnar*, I would say it as above (not all English adverbs are regular, so they don't necessarily correspond to each other). If I was writing it from scratch I'd change 'columnar'.